# How to call public class from main console?

Tags: c#, class, if-statement, methods

so I'm creating a small program and am having trouble calling a public class from my main console. In the main console, the class is to be called if the user selects a certain choice. The class is called within an if-statement if(choice == "1"} {(class is called)}. I'll also note there's a return statement at the bottom of the second class. Here's what the first three lines of the separate class look like:

```
string actChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        if (actChoice == "2")
        {
            class Kitchen; 
   

        }
class Kitchen
{
    //this class will be played when you choose 2
    public class Ren
    {
        //setting method 
        public void Meal()
```

Comment: Sure. I tried posting it the first time with it and it didn't take.

Comment: Also any reason why you are nesting classes like that. Should Run not be a method rather than class?

Comment: You cannot "call a class". You can call a method. And you can create an instance of a class.

Comment: "//this class will be played when you choose 2" Not part of your issue but "playing" a class is not really a thing here IMHO.  I would also suggest clear naming for classes - what is a `Ren` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of a class nested inside another class

```
var ren = new Kitchen.Ren() ;
```

.

```
string actChoice = Console.ReadLine();

switch (actChoice)
{
    case "1":
        
        break;
        case "2":
            Kitchen.Ren ren = new(); // One way to do it
        ren.Meal();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
class Kitchen
{
    public class Ren
    {
        public void Meal()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OK Meal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a class you need to create a new instance of that class.
Unless this class is `static`, and in that case everything inside it (methods fields etc..) should be static as well.

How to create a new class for example:

```
var kitchenInstance = new Kitchen();
```

So this is how you should do it:

```
string actChoice = Console.ReadLine();

if (actChoice == "2")
{
    var kitchenInstance = new Kitchen(); 
}

class Kitchen
{
    //this class will be played when you choose 2
    public class Ren
    {
        //setting method 
        public void Meal()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Watch a few videos on classes and some example of them to strengthen your knowledge about them.